# Can I play audio from computer through VOIP connection?

Tags: audio, voip, soundflower

I'm using join.me for online presentations. If I have a video I'd like to share, I can't send the sound to join.me. I was thinking perhaps some Soundflower set up might enable this function. Any ideas about that, or other ways to send audio to a VOIP-type connection online?

Answer (score 1):

I am open to other thoughts, but did find this:

[http://support.citrixonline.com/en_US/Meeting/knowledge_articles/000187248?title=Attendees+Unable+to+Hear+Audio+When+Playing+a+Video+(Mac+Presenter)](http://support.citrixonline.com/en_US/Meeting/knowledge_articles/000187248?title=Attendees%20Unable%20to%20Hear%20Audio%20When%20Playing%20a%20Video%20(Mac%20Presenter))